# How to call a javascript function from a JSON string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, http-post

If I do an AJAX post with jQuery that looks like

```
 $.post('MyApp/GetPostResult.json', function(data) {
    // what goes here?
 });
```

and the result looks like

```
{
    "HasCallback": true,
    "Callback": "function(){ alert('I came from the server'); }"
};
```

Then how do I call the Callback function?  Can I just write `if(data.HasCallback){data.Callback();}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
function(data) {
  if(data.HasCallback) {
    eval(data.Callback);
  }
}
```

Edit: Didn't look quite carefully enough. If you're indeed getting the `function() { ... }` text, then you need to `eval(data.Callback + "()")`.

Comment: What exactly does `eval` do, and where would I find that documentation?

Comment: @SLaks, thanks.  The "Don't use eval!" section says eval is a security risk.  Do you by chance know of any good documentation/resources about when that concern is applicable?

Comment: It's a security risk if you can't trust the source of the function text, leaving you vulnerable to [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). If you're just getting the JS from your server, there's no risk.

Comment: @Ben Alpert, the question you should ask is not whether the data comes from the server, but whether the data comes from a trusted source.  If your server forwards data from an untrusted source uncritically, then you are still vulnerable to XSS.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem

Comment: @Mike, that's a good point, but presumably if I am making a client-side call to a server-side function, then I will know how the server is providing the resource.

Comment: @smartcaveman, Sure, if you tell someone "don't eval data from untrusted sources", then they can figure out what is safe to eval based on their knowledge of the server.  But if you tell someone "it is safe to eval data that comes from the server", without knowing about the server yourself, then you are doing them a disservice.

Answer (score 1):

```
eval("(" + functionDeclarationAsString + ")()");
```

while `functionDeclaractionAsString` would be something in the form of 
`function(){ alert('I came from the server'); }`

**EDIT**

The notation (functionReference)(); is used to call a reference to a function. The following would be valid:

```
(function() { alert('it works'); })();
```

The following also would be valid:

```
var my_function = function(param) { alert(param); };
(my_function)('this is a parameter');
```

Comment: Why are the additional parentheses needed and what role do they play?

Comment: the aditional parentheses mean that you want to call the function that is declared within the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

It's a better idea to keep code and data separate. To use your example, why not have JSON like this:

```
{
    "Message": "I came from the server"
}
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
$.post('MyApp/GetPostResult.json', function(data) {
    if (data.Message) {
        alert(data.Message);
    }
});
```

Comment: Because I can maximize code reusability and cutdown on user-interface implementation time by generating the client-side code server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the evil `eval` to execute the given string as code:

```
if (data.HasCallback) {
  eval("("+data.Callback+"());");
}
```

The additional parentheses at the end execute your function immediately.

[Documented at the evil w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp)