# Passing a JavaScript function from JSON encoded PHP

Tags: php, javascript, function, highcharts, typeerror

PHP - This is part of a Highchart configuration array that is returned by a PHP function (which is json_encoded)

```
'plotOptions' => array(
    'pie' => array(
        'allowPointSelect'  => TRUE,
        'cursor'            => 'pointer',
        'dataLabels'        => array(
            'enabled'           => TRUE,
            'color'             => '#000000',
            'connectorColor'    => '#000000',
            'formatter'         => "function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %' }"
        )
    )
)
```

JavaScript - Accessing this information from the encoded data

```
container.highcharts(r.hc);
// r.hc is the array that contains the highchart information above
```

The problem I'm having is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function() { return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+
this.percentage +' %' } has no method 'call'
```

How do I change this so it recognizes it as a function? Or is this even possible?

Comment: Why do you use double quotes there and single quotes everywhere else ?

Comment: So you are trying to pass a Javascript function to a PHP script? or vice-versa?

Comment: @nifr Notice how there are single quotes in the function? I would have to escape the single quotes inside in order to use single quotes to wrap it.

Comment: @thatidiotguy Its a javascript function in a string that is passed to javascript using AJAX ...

Comment: Your function is a string object when it is decoded into your JavaScript from JSON, not a function object. You're going to have to do something like `eval` on it. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3946958/pass-function-in-json-and-execute) and [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5494127/how-to-call-a-javascript-function-from-a-json-string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Executing javascript from a remote source is a bad idea as you can't trust it. However, if you must:

The function included in the json is a string therefore you need to evaluate it:

```
 pie.dataLabels.formatter = eval('('+pie.dataLabels.formatter+')');
```

for each method of the object that needs to be converted.

However, as said at the start, there is almost certainly a solution that does not require you to fetch javascript in this way.

Comment: Using eval caused the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (" ... which makes me think that it can't eval unnamed functions. Either way, I'm not gonna pass a string for the function ... I'll just pass other data and use javascript to set up the configuration

Comment: I forgot to surround the string in parentheses - these are needed so that eval knows it is evaluating an expression. I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to only return series data for the pie highchart ... instead of the whole highchart configuration array ... plotOptions are now defined in javascript and not returned by a json_encoded PHP array ..

I'm not too sure why I was doing that but thanks for all the help with eval!